# Qt5: Native looking widgets on Android

Tags: android, c++, qt, qt5, look-and-feel

I tried Qt5 on Android, but all widgets I tested (except `QMenu`) are just grey and don't look native at all. The [Qt5.1 alpha announcement](http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2013/04/08/qt-5-1-alpha-available/) blog post says *"Of course, they have the look and feel of native widgets of the underlying platforms"*, so I guess I'm doing something wrong.

Is there a list of widgets that work nicely on mobile, or do I have to set some variable to get it working?

Comment: I think there are lots of Qt/C++ developers like us that are really interested on use Qt for mobile development. It could be great if we reach a way to share code and learn about this area. I have experienced the same as you in the last minutes, BUT, the thing is that we have CSS for Qt and widgets can look really cooool! try it!

Answer (score 2):

This phrase is about Qt Quick controls, not QtWidgets module. There is a possibility that QtWidgets will never look as native on Android. For example they doesn't look as native on Meego. Qt Quick has the top priority for Qt's mobile support.